# twitter bootstrap column classes are not working in table

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

user@email.comI'm trying to fit a bootstrap table inside my content area. I found Eric Saupe's tutorial [here](http://ericsaupe.com/custom-column-widths-in-bootstrap-tables/) on using bootstraps default column classes in `th` to fix the width of the `td`, but in my firefox, it doesn't seem to work. my `table` is below:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 p-l-xlg">


                <table class="records_list table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th class="col-md-1">Name</th>
                        <th class="col-md-1">Organization</th>
                        <th class="col-md-1">Designation</th>
                        <th class="col-md-1">Address</th>
                        <th class="col-md-1">Office Phone</th>
                        <th class="col-md-1">Resident Phone</th>
                        <th class="col-md-1">Mobile</th>
                        <th class="col-md-1">Email</th>
                        <th class="col-md-1">Relation</th>
                        <th class="col-md-1">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for ref in reference %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ ref.name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ ref.organization }}</td>
                            <td>{{ ref.designation }}</td>
                            <td>{{ ref.address }}</td>
                            <td>{{ ref.phoneOff }}</td>
                            <td>{{ ref.phoneRes }}</td>
                            <td>{{ ref.mobile }}</td>
                            <td>user@email.com</td>
                            <td>{{ ref.getRelationReadable }}</td>

                            <td>
                                <a  href="{{ path('applicant_profile_reference_edit', { 'id': ref.id }) }}"  class="btn btn-login editlightbox">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>

                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>


                </table>
        </div>
```

I don't have any additional css for this table other than what bootstrap has by default. I actually need to resize the email td, since that is the biggest, but putting the class in that th only is not working either. What am I doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: All the col-md-* values add up to 13. Bootstrap uses 12 column layout so not sure how this will lay out.

Comment: I've knocked up a bootply, in what way does it not work for you? http://www.bootply.com/Jb9Q4dljvL

Comment: oops....typing mistake...I hit four in stead of 1! editing! :p

Comment: OK, so what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: the email column should be smaller, that is my goal....it isn't!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to make the email field smaller, change the `col-md-4` of that email `<th>` to a lesser number and allocate it elsewhere. I tested that on the above bootply and there are no issues on Firefox or Webkit.

Comment: could you please post your bootply? I updated the code, the 4 was a typing mistake. all of them should be 1 column. it is still not working for me. I have substituted the `{{ ref.email }}' field with an actual email, so it is still wide.

Comment: @SamiaRuponti this is a fork of DavidG's above bootply with the col-* values changed to 1. This appears to be what you're asking for http://www.bootply.com/IBIONXwKBn

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using something that I don't like, but it works (at least in this circumstance). I am having space problem in medium screen, so I added a helper class and added this to my stylesheet:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {

td.tolong {
    max-width:5em;word-wrap: break-word}
}
```

The `break-word` property makes the table looks ugly, so this is not the best solution. But it works in my case.